# Long as key in map

Tags: gwt

I received a Map from server.

And when I'm trying to get value from this map, null is always returned, but I am sure, that map contains such value:

```
public void updateView(Map<Long, JavaScriptObjectImpl> data) {
    table.setRowData(new ArrayList<JavaScriptObjectImpl>(data.values()));
    table.redraw();
    if (selectedFileId != -1) {
        JavaScriptObjectImpl object =data.get(selectedFileId); // null is returned
        consoleLog(String.valueOf(selectedFileId));  // this line prints "11001"
        consoleLog(String.valueOf(data));            // this line prints "{11001=[object Object]}"
        boolean b = data.containsKey(selectedFileId);
        consoleLog(String.valueOf(b));               // this line prints "false"

        ...
    }
}
```

Does anyone know is it possible to use Long as key in Map in gwt?
Or help me with my problem, please

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Long as key in Map in gwt?

Yes, there is no constraint in GWT for Long as key in Map.

---

Please have a look at this line directly from your code.

```
consoleLog(String.valueOf(data)); // this line prints "{11001=[object Object]}"
```

Its clearly visible that `data` contains a key `11001` and a value that is `not null`.

If the value is `null` then it will print something like  `{11001=null}`

Comment: It is long. It's class field
    private Long selectedFileId;

Comment: OK let me try to find out other possibilities.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are putting it in map.

Comment: try `System.out.println(data.keySet());` to print the keys.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < allFilesInfo.length(); i++) {
            JavaScriptObjectImpl info = allFilesInfo.get(i);
            resultMap.put(info.getFileId(), info);
        }`

Comment: What is data type of return value of `info.getFileId()` method?

Comment: Long. It is field in JavaScriptObjectImpl

Comment: `consoleLog(data.keySet().toString())` prints [11001]

Comment: That is the reason - value is not null, but I cannot retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the reason of the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allFilesInfo.length(); i++) {
        FileInfoJS info = allFilesInfo.get(i);
        filesInfo.put(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(info.getFileId())), info);
}
```

When I formed map, value of info.getFileId() was not Long, but JSObject.
Unfortunately, I cannot explain it.